# How to pass TextField with entered data into form after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I have a TextField and a Button (both are material-ui components) displaying on my main page. I want to be able to click the button and populate a form that includes the previous TextField and any text that had already been written in it. The code I currently have just makes a new instance of the TextField within the form, while keeping the original TextField as well. How can I bring the existing TextField over into the form without duplicating?

FormTextField.js

```
const FormTextField = props => {
    return (
        <TextField
            fullWidth={true}
            multiline={true}
            rows="10"
            variant="outlined"
        >
        {props.data}
        </TextField>

    )
}

export default class FormTextField extends Component {
    render() {
    data={this.props.data} />
    return (

        {FormTextField}

        );
    }
};
```

Form.js

```
const Form= () => {
return (
    <FormLabel">Input Text...</FormLabel>
    <FormTextField />
);}
export default Form;
```

App.js

```
const AddButton= (props) => {
return (
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.onClick}>
    New Interaction
    </Button>
    )
}


export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {show: false};
}
showForm = () => {
    this.setState({
        show: true,
    });
}
render() {
    return(
    <Fragment>
        <Header />
        <FormTextField />
        <AddButton onClick={this.showInteractionForm} />{this.state.show ? 
<Form /> : null}
    </Fragment>
    );
}

};
```

Comment: do you want that the FormTextField outside From be the same? or the data in the FormTextField be in the FormTextField inside Form?

Comment: I want the main page to display the FormTextField along with the button, with the form hidden. When I click the button, I want the form to populate and merge FormTextField into it with any existing data in the TextField. I realize I'm calling it twice here... but I'm not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to share data between two components you can resolve this in different ways, based in your code, a solution could be:

Your `App` control the data so,

in your state can add:

```
this.state = {
 inputData = '';
}
```

You need to pass an update function to your `FromTextField`

```
<FormTextField onTextUpdate={(text) => this.setState({ inputData: text })} />
```

Your form field must be controlled by `App` so you need to pass the data to be shown too:

```
<FormTextField data={this.state.inputData} onTextUpdate={(text) => this.setState({ inputData: text })} />
```

(you need to add that modification to FormTextField, they are easy)

And the last step is to do the same with `Form`

```
<Form data={this.state.inputData} onTextUpdate={(text) => this.setState({ inputData: text })} />
```

Inside `Form` you need to pass `data` and `onTextUpdate` to the `FormTextField`

You can refactor `(text) => this.setState({ inputData: text })` to be a method in class.

**EDIT**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/stackoverflow-form-react-9188m you can find the implementation about I told you before.

Comment: I'm getting an error with inputData not being defined in App.js. The way I'm writing it is     this.state = {show: false,
        inputData = ''}; in the constructor

Comment: See the link I posted